# How to change route or component based on query parameters

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

Working with Angular, I have a URL that is being passed to my app, it has query parameters that define what should happen on the page, much like a route.

for example

```
http://localhost/?r=error&m=errorMessage
http://localhost/?r=registered&id=1234
```

if it were a usual route I would do the following

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component:AnnouncementComponent},
  { path: 'error', component:ErrorComponent},
  { path: 'registered', component: RegisteredComponent },
];
```

is it possible to have some sort of parameter as a route selector?
Or in my AnnounceComponent, how could I swap in the Error or Registered Component?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with routing, but there is a way to dynamically load component based on query params.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating a component that did the routing for me.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-param-route',
  templateUrl: './param-route.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./param-route.component.scss']
})
export class ParamRouteComponent implements OnInit {
  route: string;
  message: string;

  constructor(private Activatedroute:ActivatedRoute,
    private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route = this.Activatedroute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('r')||null;
    this.message = this.Activatedroute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('m')||null;

    this.Activatedroute.queryParamMap
        .subscribe(params => { 
          this.route = params.get('r')||null;
          console.log('Query params ',this.route) 
      });

  }
}
```

Then in the component HTML, I can just specify when each route would change.

```
<app-error *ngIf="route === 'error'" [message]="this.message"></app-error>
<app-registered *ngIf="route === 'registered'" [message]="this.message"></app-registered>
<app-announcement *ngIf="route === null"></app-announcement>
```

my use case was small and manageable like this, I"m not sure if the flexibility of using parameters as routes would be useful when you don't have full control of the app.